# Group Checkboxes on Submit

Tags: html, checkbox, get

I have a form like this

```
<form action=''>
<label for="carrot">Carrot Collection</label><input type="checkbox" id="carrot" name="skills" value="carrot"><br>
<label for="potato">Potato Collection</label><input type="checkbox" id="potato" name="skills" value="potato"><br>
<button type='submit'>Neu Laden</button><br>
```

When I press the Button i currently get:

`foo.bar/test.html?skills=carrot&skills=potato`

Is there an easy way to achieve something like `foo.bar/test.html?skills=carrot,potato`
There will be an awful lot of Checkboxes and it would be quite a pain to query all of them to build the Request string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post doesn't work in my case. I need to provide the Set in the query.

So what i did was:

```
<button type='button' onclick='submitSkills()'>Neu Laden</button>
function submitSkills() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("skills");
  var skills = "";

  for(i = 0;i < checkboxes.length; i++)
  { 
      if (checkboxes[i].checked)            
          skills = skills + ","+checkboxes[i].value;
  }
}
```

and providing the skills in the query.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't, the two params aren't the sames so they will be stored in different variables (here you see two skills, but it's only their name, behind it's not the same variable).

What you might be looking for is not sending your data with GET method but using POST.
Using the POST method will remove all the parameters from the link.

```
<form method="post" action="">
```